# How can i setpayload on xml config?

Tags: mule

i want to set some message to payload.

i always used filter to set some data to payload.

i think they are some ways to setpayload whith out using filter.

could somebody help me how to setpayload on the mule-config.xml file ?

i tried

```
<set-payload value="something"/>
```

but doesn't works .. i am using mule 3.2

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The set-payload transformer is available starting with Mule 3.3.

For 3.2, the shortest is expression-transformer:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Expression+Transformer+Reference

Comment: Could you provide an example using Expression Transformer?